# Change global variable value using pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, global-variables, assign

I have problem with my code. my global variable not changed. I have assigned its address to a pointer. This is my struct initialization:

```
    struct PortData {
        int port;
        int sent;
        int received;
        int total;
        struct PortData *Next;
    };

    struct IPData {
        time_t timestamp;
        uint32_t ip;
        struct PortData Record;
    };
```

this is my function which returned the address:

```
    inline struct IPData *FindIp(uint32_t ipaddr) {
    unsigned int counter;

    for (counter = 0; counter < IpCount; counter++)
        if (IpTable[counter].ip == ipaddr)
            return (&IpTable[counter]);

    if (IpCount >= IP_NUM) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "IP_NUM is too low, dropping ip....");
        return (NULL);
    }

    memset(&IpTable[IpCount], 0, sizeof (struct IPData));
    IpTable[IpCount].ip = ipaddr;
    return (&IpTable[IpCount++]); 
    }
```

and here where the pointer assigned to the address of `IpTable`:

```
    struct IPData *ptrIPData;
    for (Count = 0; Count < SubnetCount; Count++) {
        if (SubnetTable[Count].ip == (iph->saddr & SubnetTable[Count].mask)) {
            ptrIPData = FindIp(iph->saddr);
            Credit(&(ptrIPData->Record), iph, tcph, srcip);          
        }    
        if (SubnetTable[Count].ip == (iph->daddr & SubnetTable[Count].mask)) {
            ptrIPData = FindIp(iph->daddr);
            Credit(&(ptrIPData->Record), iph, tcph, dstip);
        }

    }
```

This is my Credit() function:

```
inline void Credit(struct PortData *pordt, struct iphdr *iph, struct tcphdr *tcph, struct in_addr sipaddr) {

    unsigned int sport, dport;

    memset(&source, 0, sizeof (source));
    source.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->saddr; //init source ip
    sport = ntohs(tcph->source);

    memset(&dest, 0, sizeof (dest));
    dest.sin_addr.s_addr = iph->daddr; //init dest ip
    dport = ntohs(tcph->dest);

    packet_size = ntohs(iph->tot_len);
    if (iph->protocol == 6) //6 is protocol TCP
    {
        prev = portdt;
        int sameport = 0;
        while (prev != NULL) {
            if (dport == prev->port || sport == prev->port) {
                if (dport == prev->port) {
                    prev->sent += packet_size;
                }
                if (sport == prev->port) {
                    prev->received += packet_size;
                }
                sameport = 1;
                break;
            }            
        }

        if (sameport == 0) {
            printf("create new node\n");
            newnode = (struct PortData*) malloc(sizeof (struct PortData));
            newnode->received = 0;
            newnode->sent = 0;
            if (sipaddr.s_addr == source.sin_addr.s_addr) {
                if (tcph->syn == 1 || tcph->ack == 1) {
                    newnode->port = dport;
                    newnode->sent = packet_size;
                }
            }
            if (sipaddr.s_addr == dest.sin_addr.s_addr) {
                if (tcph->syn == 1 && tcph->ack == 1) {
                    newnode->port = sport;
                    newnode->received = packet_size;
                }
            }
            newnode->Next = portdt;
            portdt = newnode;
        }//==end-sameport==
    }//iph->protocol//

    prev = portdt;
    while (prev != NULL) {
        fprintf(logfile, "ip = %s port=%d sent=%d bytes received=%d bytes\n", inet_ntoa(sipaddr), prev->port, prev->sent, prev->received);
        prev = prev->Next;
    }
}
```

I assumed after executed the `Credit()` function, value of `Iptable[Counter].Record` must changed because `ptrIPData` pointed to it address. but why it does not?

Comment: A few off topic comments: don't cast the pointer returned by the malloc. You can avoid to write `if (tcph->syn == 1 && tcph->ack == 1)` twice by moving it. Be consistent in your variable naming: CamelCase or lower?

Comment: Have you check `iph->protocol` is really `6`?

Comment: `while (prev != NULL)` can become infinite loop if `prev` is not `NULL` before entering loop, because `prev` is never assigned inside loop.

Comment: my `Credit()` function works properly. The number of sent and received has increased by the `packet_size` when this function executed.
okay, I will assigned the `prev` into NULL.

Comment: Oh sorry, you seems try to insert new value in the beginning of link list, in that case, try @David's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert a new item into the linked list `Record`. You attempt to do this by writing:

```
newnode = (struct PortData*) malloc(sizeof (struct PortData));
// initialise newnode
newnode->Next = portdt;
portdt = newnode;
```

The problem is that `portdt` is local variable that contains the address of the `Record` member of an `IPData` struct. So assigning to the local variable `portdt` achieves nothing that is visible outside the function.

You'll need to make a couple of changes. First of all you need to change `struct PortData Record` to `struct PortData *Record`. This is the head pointer of your list, and it must be declared as a pointer to node and not as you have done as a node value.

Then you still pass `&Record` to `Credit`, but now `portdt` is of type `struct PortData **Record`. So the node insertion assignment becomes

```
newnode = malloc(sizeof (struct PortData));
// initialise newnode
newnode->Next = *portdt;
*portdt = newnode;
```

---

There are other problems with your code. I'm not going to attempt to list them all, but here's what I have seen:

- Don't cast the return value of `malloc`.
- You ought to check the return value of `malloc` for errors.
- Declare `prev` to be a local variable rather than a global as it currently appears to be.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. then am I need to declare `**prev` instead of `*prev`? I need to use `prev` for searching node inside `portdt`.
if I declared **prev, I don't know the next syntax for the `while(prev != NULL)`, accessing `dport = prev->port` etc. I'm new in using pointer to pointer like this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `portdt = newnode;`, you should replace line with:

```
portdt->port = newnode->port;
portdt->sent = newnode->sent;
portdt->received = newnode->received;
portdt->total = newnode->total;
portdt->Next = newnode->Next;
```

Like @David says, `portdt = newnode;` is only change local variable only, not change something that `portdt` pointed.